# Automapper - Convert UTC to Specific timezone

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following  which when translating `DateUtc` from source to dest `Date`, I want to apply a conversion.  Now the following converter I wrote will work for a specific field because that is specified.

I would like my converter to be more flexible that I can pass the other object than `SourceDto1`, `DestDto1` such as `SourceDto2` and `DestDto2`

```
public class SourceDto1
{
   public DateTime DateUtc {get;set;}
}
public class DestDto1
{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
public class SourceDto2
{
   public DateTime DateUtc {get;set;}
}
public class DestDto2
{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

converter

```
public class AttachmentCreatedDateResolver : IValueResolver<SourceDto1, DestDto1 DateTime>
    {

        private readonly Settings _settings;
        public AttachmentCreatedDateResolver(Settings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }


        public DateTime Resolve(SourceDto1 source, DestDto1 destination, DateTime destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(_settings.TimeZone);
            var converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(source.DateUtc, tzi);
            return converted;
        }
    }
```

I guess i dont want to create a different resolver class for every pair of objects I have that I need to convert dates between properties.

`ITypeConverter` might work but I was not sure how to inject my `Settings` from DI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an implementation of [`IMemberValueResolver`](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#customizing-the-source-value-supplied-to-the-resolver) for this:

```
public class AttachmentCreatedDateResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, DateTime, DateTime>
{
    private readonly Settings _settings;
    public AttachmentCreatedDateResolver(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public DateTime Resolve(object source, object destination, DateTime sourceMember, DateTime destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(_settings.TimeZone);
        var converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceMember, tzi);
        return converted;
    }
}
```

This behaves similar to an implementation of `IValueResolver`, allowing you to inject dependencies into the resolver while also allowing you to use it at the member level for any object (note that the source and destination types are set to `object`). You'd then be able to configure this same resolver for each type mapping with something like:

```
CreateMap<SourceDto1, DestDto1>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom<AttachmentCreatedDateResolver, DateTime>(s => s.DateUtc));
CreateMap<SourceDto2, DestDto2>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom<AttachmentCreatedDateResolver, DateTime>(s => s.DateUtc));
```

Comment: Alternatively, an `IValueResolver` could still be used if the Source and Dest are interfaced. The map can then simply be `CreateMap<ISrc, IDest>().ForMember(...).IncludeAllDerived()`. This would cover all the implementing DTOs.

Comment: This used to be the way. But now this case is more streamlined. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html